# How to make Wordpress using local CSS/Fonts/Scripts only

Tags: css, offline

For people in remote places with a bad internet connection, working on Wordpress stuff becomes real horror, not to mention : expensive!

Switching to a simple theme with no external dependencies could be a quick solution but I'd be interested in something more elegant. Is there a simple possibility to force Wordpress to cache external resources and rewrite the URLS?

Possibly there are plugins doing that already. 
any idea is welcome!
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin [Airplane Mode](https://github.com/norcross/airplane-mode) that tweaks good chunk of network–related things core does.

I am not entirely sure which kinds of external resources you mean. If you import site and its media into local development installation then most of it will be local already.

Comment: you again:-) airplane-mode works for me! thank you! external resources : fonts/css ... wp seems to use google fonts now, on a slow internet connection its a cruel to wait for them, no matter how small they are.

Comment: There are plugins around to kill google fonts too, going that way was just all kinds of bad idea for core. :\

Comment: sure, i understand. i introduced for that "alternate resources" in my apps. something you can activate through an URL parameter. thats nice also for testing and lots of other things like switching between debug/release versions of the same resource...well, just saying :-)